# Use APC instead of session in CodeIgniter,is it good way?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, apc

I'm developing high traffic web site by CodeIgniter,sessions are stored in database because of security.

Is it good way to use apc instead of session to store something like logged in users and other security things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it's a bad idea because APC caches are [not shared](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57825) between individual php processes (php-fpm could be an exception). Furthermore they won't be able to support multiple clustered environment without linking the user to a certain frontent which you want to avoid in a clustered environment (hurts load balancing, prevents failover).

Look into the [memchace session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php), it's fast, and can be clustered easily and probably already built in to your php install. Ofcourse you will have to install a memcached on your server.